# What permissions does an Organisation Owner have in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

We've been using Azure DevOps but I'm wondering what the Organisation Owner does? Do they have extra permissions in Azure DevOps or is it just a 'for info' type field so people know who to speak with about any DevOps queries / change requests with the setup.

Thinking ours may need to change but just looking to see what the impact is in changing that - i.e. what permissions would the existing person lose (and what would a new person gain) if that was to change to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, there aren't extra permissions for the owner account, so, just feel free to change owner. For the new owner, he has the admin permission.

On the other hand, you may just add the new user to Project Collection administrators group, then this new user will has admin permission too.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/lookup-organization-owner-admin?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)

> An administrator or organization Owner can give you access to select
> features or functions, or change your permissions. In this article,
> learn how to look up administrators or organization Owners.

and here are the [`rights or things`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions-access?view=azure-devops#notifications-alerts-and-team-collaboration-tools) that organization owner can do.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, as an organization Owner, you are the administrator of your DevOps service and you have super permission. You can manage your project, includes:

- Add users to your project
- Grant or restrict permissions
- Share your project vision and support collaboration
- Remove unused services from the user interface
- Set code, test, and other policies
- Define area and iteration paths for work tracking
- Customize work-tracking processes
- Review and update notifications
- Add teams to scale your organization
- Install and manage extensions
- Set up billing

Detailed information, you can refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/project-admin-tutorial?view=azure-devops